# The math on the total is not correct

Tags: java

The math on this code does not add up when doing multiple customers, I have tried changing a lot of stuff .

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dinerBill {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    double taxRate = 0,  customerTotalBeforeDiscount= 0 , customerTotal =0   , discountType = 0, grandTotal= 0;


    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String [] itemName = { "0) Soup", "1) Wing", "2) Burger", "3) Chicken Sandwich", "4) Fries", "5) Pie", "6) Ice Cream", "7) Soft drink", "8) Coffee"};
    double [] itemPrice= {2.50 , .15 , 4.95, 5.95, 1.99, 2.95, 2.99, 1.50, 1.00};

    System.out.println("Enter the number of people in the party");
    int numberOfPeople  = in.nextInt();

    while (numberOfPeople >0) {

    System.out.println("Enter 1 if customer recieves teen or eldery discount ");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 if the customer recieves no discount");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 if the customer is under 5");
    discountType = in.nextInt();



    if (discountType == 1) {
        discountType = .75;
         taxRate = 1;
    }
    else if (discountType ==2) {
        discountType = 1;
        taxRate = 1.05;
    }
    else if (discountType ==3) {
        discountType = 0;}
    else {
        System.out.println("invalid discount type entered");
        System.exit(0);}




    System.out.printf("%-24s", "Menu");
    System.out.print("Prices" + "\n");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < itemName.length; i++) {

    System.out.printf("%-24.21s" ,itemName[i]);
    System.out.print(itemPrice[i] +"\n");

    }
    System.out.println("Enter the corresponding number");


    for (int choices=3; choices > 0; choices--) {
        double choicePrice = 0;
        customerTotal=+0;   
        System.out.println("Enter customers item");
        int customerItem = in.nextInt();

        if (customerItem ==1) {
        System.out.println("How many wings ordered?");
        int wingsOrdered = in.nextInt();
        double priceOfWings = wingsOrdered * itemPrice[1];
        choicePrice = priceOfWings;}
        else
            choicePrice = itemPrice[customerItem];

         customerTotalBeforeDiscount += choicePrice;
         double customerTotalBeforeTax = customerTotalBeforeDiscount * discountType;
            customerTotal = customerTotalBeforeTax * taxRate;


    }

    grandTotal += customerTotal;

    System.out.print("The total for the customer is $" );
    System.out.printf("%.2f \n" , customerTotal );









    numberOfPeople--;
    }

    System.out.print("The total is $");
    System.out.printf("%.2f", grandTotal);

    in.close();

    System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

.

```
Enter the number of people in the party
4
Enter 1 if customer recieves teen or eldery discount 
Enter 2 if the customer recieves no discount
Enter 3 if the customer is under 5
1
Menu                    Prices
--------------------------------
0) Soup                 2.5
1) Wing                 0.15
2) Burger               4.95
3) Chicken Sandwich     5.95
4) Fries                1.99
5) Pie                  2.95
6) Ice Cream            2.99
7) Soft drink           1.5
8) Coffee               1.0
Enter the corresponding number
Enter customers item
0
Enter customers item
2
Enter customers item
8
The total for the customer is $6.34 
Enter 1 if customer recieves teen or eldery discount 
Enter 2 if the customer recieves no discount
Enter 3 if the customer is under 5
2
Menu                    Prices
--------------------------------
0) Soup                 2.5
1) Wing                 0.15
2) Burger               4.95
3) Chicken Sandwich     5.95
4) Fries                1.99
5) Pie                  2.95
6) Ice Cream            2.99
7) Soft drink           1.5
8) Coffee               1.0
Enter the corresponding number
Enter customers item
1
How many wings ordered?
5
Enter customers item
2
Enter customers item
8
The total for the customer is $15.91 
Enter 1 if customer recieves teen or eldery discount 
Enter 2 if the customer recieves no discount
Enter 3 if the customer is under 5
2
Menu                    Prices
--------------------------------
0) Soup                 2.5
1) Wing                 0.15
2) Burger               4.95
3) Chicken Sandwich     5.95
4) Fries                1.99
5) Pie                  2.95
6) Ice Cream            2.99
7) Soft drink           1.5
8) Coffee               1.0
Enter the corresponding number
Enter customers item
0
Enter customers item
2
Enter customers item
7
The total for the customer is $25.31 
Enter 1 if customer recieves teen or eldery discount 
Enter 2 if the customer recieves no discount
Enter 3 if the customer is under 5
3
Menu                    Prices
--------------------------------
0) Soup                 2.5
1) Wing                 0.15
2) Burger               4.95
3) Chicken Sandwich     5.95
4) Fries                1.99
5) Pie                  2.95
6) Ice Cream            2.99
7) Soft drink           1.5
8) Coffee               1.0
Enter the corresponding number
Enter customers item
2
Enter customers item
7
Enter customers item
6
The total for the customer is $0.00 
The total is $47.55
```

Comment: Your post is kind of hard to read.  Can you give a specific example of what input you're providing, what output you _think_ you should get, and what output you _actually_ get?  For what it's worth, using `double` to store an amount of money is a recipe for disaster - you're very likely to get floating point errors.  A better data type for storing money is `BigDecimal`.  But without more information, it's hard to know whether that's the problem you're facing here.

Comment: yeah it did not print the way I pasted it from the console sorry. like on customer 2 under the second menu prices, a burger, 5 wings and a coffee printed the customer total at $15.91, then it put the total at 25.31 for customer 3 and for customer 4 the customer total is right at $0 and the grand total added up correctly it looks like the customer totals in 2 and 3 are wrong

Comment: So what were you expecting the numbers to be?  For customer 2, should it be $6.70?  If that's the case, then this is obviously more than just a floating point error.  As I said in my earlier comment, your question would be much clearer if you could state the EXPECTED output, as well as the ACTUAL output.

Comment: For a start if `discountType ==3` then `taxRate = 0` so everything is free!

Comment: the $6.34 is right for customer 1 , customer 2 is supposed to be $7.04, customer 3 is supposed to be $9.40, and customer 4 is $0.00 for a grand total of $22.78

Comment: If you are using eclipse, try to run your code in debug mode with break point so it shows the run-time value of variables. If you are using other IDEs there is probably similar way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            for (int choices = 3; choices > 0; choices--) {
            double choicePrice = 0;

            System.out.println("Enter customers item");
            int customerItem = in.nextInt();

            if (customerItem == 1) {
                System.out.println("How many wings ordered?");
                int wingsOrdered = in.nextInt();
                double priceOfWings = wingsOrdered * itemPrice[1];
                choicePrice = priceOfWings;
            } else
                choicePrice = itemPrice[customerItem];

            customerTotal += choicePrice * (discountType * taxRate);

        }

        grandTotal += customerTotal;

        System.out.print("The total for the customer is $");
        System.out.printf("%.2f \n", customerTotal);

        customerTotal = 0;
```

after breaking down it was easier to combine the discount and taxType into customer total together. Than I had to make sure customerTotal was zeroing out after adding to grand total and printing.